# Confused with testing my paypal subscribe buttons

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have my website and opened a paypal business account. I have setup the payment links using wishlist member and created the paypal buttons that I need to add to my website.

Now, I have the Subscribe buttons ready and they link to paypal...my problem is that I need to test it and not pay for it myself.

I DID open a sandbox paypal account too but the email and password given in paypal sanbox doesn't  work on paypal and the Paypal Button code is not linking to the sandbox...it links to actual paypal.

How I'm I supposed to test these buttons if they link to paypal and not to sandbox?

How does this work? Do I need to create new buttons at Sandbox and if yes...then I'm not really testing my all ready setup right?

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in thinking you need to re-create these buttons under your Sandbox account in order to simulate payment without actually paying. Your Sandbox account will generate the button code with the correct sandbox links.

Moreover, when testing your Sandbox buttons, you need to use your Sandbox test account credentials to simulate the payment. Do not use actual credit card information, regardless of whether PayPal allows it or not, you're just testing.

**Note**: The only differences between your actual button code and Sandbox button code *should* only be the form action and button identifier.

Such as,

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
// versus
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

AND

```
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="FLVPFBWCKGND8">  // Actual
// versus
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SNDBXGENERATD">  // Sandbox
```

Or, if you're not using 'hosted buttons' (the details aren't stored with PayPal):

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your-real@email.tld">    // Actual
// versus
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your-sandbox@email.tld"> // Sandbox
```

The easiest way to identify whether you're using hosted buttons or not, is to see if you've got "hosted_button_id" in your form code. If you do, you're using hosted buttons.

For a better understanding/explanation of how Sandbox is setup/integrated: [Testing PayPal Website Features](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_website_features.html), or [Sandbox User Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide.pdf)

Comment: Add some info. re. hosted vs non-hosted buttons.